# Migrating data from mongo database to another

Tags: mongodb, go, data-migration, mongo-go-driver

I have two database connections `docDb` and `mongoDb` each having three databases `db1`,`db2`, and `db3`. I want to read all data from `db1` of `docDb` to `db1` of `mongoDb` in Go using `mongo-driver` and I want to do the same for other databases as well.

This is what I have so far,

```
func MigrateData(mongoConnection *mongo.Client, docDbConnection *mongo.Client){
    db1Doc := docDbConnection.Database("db1")
    db1Mongo := mongoConnection.Database("db1")

    coll_doc := db1Doc.Collection("collection_1")
    cursor, err := coll_doc.Find(context.TODO(), bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var documents []bson.M
    if err = cursor.All(context.TODO(), &documents); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    coll_mongo := db1Mongo.Collection("collection_1")
}
```

Now this `documents` consists of all the documents in `collection_1` in `db1`. But I am not able to figure out how to write these to `collection_1` of `db1` and skip if the document is already present. I did some research online but all I found was inserting custom-made document objects. But here I am getting type `[]primitive.M`.

1. How do I write these to `coll_mongo` ( `collection_1` in `db1` of `mongodb`)?
2. If I do it this way, I will need to know the collection names beforehand and migrate in between collections, or get a list of collection names and loop through it but this sounds like a workaround or a wrong way to do it. Is there another way in Go and `mongo-driver` where I can read everything from a database and directly write it to another database ( all collections, all documents )?

Answer (score 1):

execute bash script with Go
first dump db docDb with this bash command
create backup.sh file and put this command in it

```
mongodump --db=docDb --out=./
```

and then import data to mongoDb with these commands
create restore.sh file and put in it

```
mongorestore -d mongoDb -c db1  ./docDb/db1.bson --drop
mongorestore -d mongoDb -c db2  ./docDb/db2.bson --drop 
mongorestore -d mongoDb -c db3  ./docDb/db3.bson --drop
```

this is sample code in Go to exec bash command

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "exec"
   "os"
   "bytes"
   "io"
)

func main() {
    app := "bash backup.sh"
    cmd, err := exec.Run(app, []string{app, "-l"}, nil, "", exec.DevNull, exec.Pipe, exec.Pipe)

    if (err != nil) {
       fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err.String())
       return
    }

    var b bytes.Buffer
    io.Copy(&b, cmd.Stdout)
    fmt.Println(b.String())

    cmd.Close()

    app := "bash restore.sh"
    cmd, err := exec.Run(app, []string{app, "-l"}, nil, "", exec.DevNull, exec.Pipe, exec.Pipe)

    if (err != nil) {
       fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err.String())
       return
    }

    var b bytes.Buffer
    io.Copy(&b, cmd.Stdout)
    fmt.Println(b.String())

    cmd.Close()


}
```

Comment: How do I do this in code?

Comment: answer has been updated Im not go developer but I searched and find example to how execute bash command in go